# Why do drawn shapes disappear when new shapes are drawn on Android SurfaceView?

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas, surfaceview

I am drawing circles on SurfaceView on its OnTouch event. Here is the code

```
public class DrawableSurface extends SurfaceView {
    public DrawableSurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        /*Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Bubbles(handler) ,1000);*/
    }

    private final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);



    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {
            Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

            canvas.drawCircle(event.getX(), event.getY(), 50, paint);
            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Whenever a new shape is drawn some of the already drawn shapes disappear. Not all of them, but some of them disappear. And sometimes they appear back. I couldn't figure it out. Why would it be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SurfaceView Surface is double- or triple-buffered.  You're seeing things vanish and reappear when the buffers flip.

You're required to update every pixel in the draw area on every frame.  You can limit the number of pixels you update by passing a Rect to `lockCanvas()`.  See the [`lockCanvas()` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#lockCanvas()) for more information.

Comment: I read a little about it but couldn't figure out what might be the size of the rect? Should it be the size of what I am drawing?

Comment: It's a "dirty" rect, i.e. the region you intend to draw. It must be at least as large as what you want to appear on screen. I would recommend you ignore that, and just start each frame by clearing the screen and drawing all of the circles. If you have a lot of circles, do all of your rendering onto a Bitmap (create a Canvas for it with http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#Canvas(android.graphics.Bitmap) ), and then just render the entire Bitmap onto the Surface each frame.

Comment: This last comment is indeed helpful.